# Pass click event from one child component to another

Tags: angular

I have two child components on a parent component. I am trying to pass a click event or more specifically to check when a button is clicked in one of the child components and pass that to the other child component.

***Parent***

```
<app-connect-advice [memberDetails] = "memberDetails"></app-connect-advice>

<app-help-tips subtext="Before we show you your savings"></app-help-tips>
```

***Connect-advice-component(child-1)***

```
<div (click)="showConnectWindow = true">
  <div>CONNECT</div>
</div>
```

***Help-tips-component(child-2)***

```
<div class="float-right pb-4 arrow-box">
    <svg fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="0.9" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path _ngcontent-yhk-c5="" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path></svg>
</div>
```

So essentially what I want to do is if the user clicks on the `showConnectWindow` click event, then I want to inform the `Help-tips-component` that this has happened. My end goal is to apply styles based on when the click event is clicked or not.

Any idea what I can do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Subject(RXJS)`

1- Create a service

```
export class InformService {
    private informSource = new Subject();
    informStatus$ = this.informSource.asObservable();


    public warnToTipComponent() {
        this.informSource.next();
    }
}
```

2-

```
export class AppConnectAdviceComponent{

  constructor(
    ....
    private informService: InformService) { }


   public showContent(){
      showConnectWindow = true;
      informService.warnToTipComponent();
   }
}
```

in the app-connect-advice-component.html:

```
<div (click)="showContent()">
  <div>CONNECT</div>
</div>
```

3- Here, we have to subscribe to  `informStatus$` to notice when the user click on `showContent()`

```
export class AppHelpTipsComponent implements OnInit , OnDestroy {

 public subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(
    ....
    private informService: InformService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.subscription= this.informService.informStatus$.subscribe(_ => {
        // Here,  you will notice
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.subscription)
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

**[Stackblitz Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-subject-example)**

#### UPDATED

to prevent memory leak you have to unsubscribe it in the ngOnDestroy hook

```
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.subscription)
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The only thing is that I am getting an undefined on the subscribe in the AppHelpTipsComponent

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me immensely and I learned something new. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two common solutions to your problem. The first approach would be for the child component to emit an event to the parent when the click event is triggered and the parent informs the other child.
The limitation here is that this event can only be passed to the parent component and not to other components. Check out this [article](https://medium.com/@Zeroesandones/emit-an-event-from-a-child-to-parent-component-in-angular-9-7c3690c75f6).

The other possibility would be to create a service that allows you to interact with all the components you want. Have a look at [this article](https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/) for a better overview.